# Querying an image with bilinear interpolation e.e. finding RGB value in the fractional coordinates using Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a input T1 of size (1,256,256,3) i.e. images/grid of batch size 1. I have another tensor T2 of size (1, N, 2) i.e. tensor consisting of coordinates i.e. [ [10.5 , 200.787], [150.568, 190.456], …]. How do I compute functional values (using bilinear interpolation) of coordinates in T2 from T1 data?

Thanks for any help

I have tested the same functionality using tensorflow with the function "tf.contrib.resampler.resampler"

Answer (score 1):

try grid_sample:

```
torch.nn.functional.grid_sample(input, grid, mode='bilinear', padding_mode='zeros')
```

Given an input and a flow-field grid, computes the output using input values and pixel locations from grid.

For each output location ***output[n, :, h, w]***, the size-2 vector ***grid[n, h, w]*** specifies input pixel locations x and y, which are used to interpolate the output value output[n, :, h, w]. ***mode*** argument specifies nearest or bilinear interpolation method to sample the input pixels.

***coordinate*** should be in range of ***[-1, 1]***. This is because the pixel locations are normalized by the input spatial dimensions.

[sampler git example](https://github.com/alwynmathew/bilinear-sampler-pytorch/blob/master/bilinear.py) 
[pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.grid_sample)